# Randomly displaying images in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a folder full of image files whose names I've loaded into a String array.    I have a button to display them.   This works:  (XAML fragment):

```
<StackPanel >
    <Image Name="ImageViewer" Height="400" Width="400" />
</StackPanel>
```

C# fragment:

```
  void DisplayNextRandomImage()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = random.Next(_FileCount);  // pick a random file
        string selectedFileName = _sRoot + "\\" + _sFiles[num];
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(selectedFileName);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        ImageViewer.Source = bitmap; 
    }

    // "Next" button handler
    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNextRandomImage();
    }
```

When I click on the Next button it displays a new image. If I click on it again it displays another image.  But what I really want is to display a sequence of random images with a 10 second wait between each one.   But if I change the Next button handler to this :

```
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayNextRandomImage();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    DisplayNextRandomImage();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    DisplayNextRandomImage();
}
```

It doesn't display anything.

Is there something I need to call or run in between the sleeps to cause some thread to wake up and display the image?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use storyboard animation

Comment: If ever you have `Thread.Sleep(...)` in your code you are probably doing something wrong. In this case you're sleeping the UI thread so no wonder it doesn't update!

Comment: You should also avoid calling `Random random = new Random();` within methods. It's best to do a single random object in your app to avoid duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayNextRandomImage();

            Dispatcher disp = ImageViewer.Dispatcher;
            DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Normal, timer_Tick , disp);
            t.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayNextRandomImage();
        }
```

You can also use as shorthand notation :

```
DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), DispatcherPriority.Normal, (s1,e1)=>{DisplayNextRandomImage();} , disp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of doing things is to use a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189084(v=vs.95).aspx), the callback happens on the main thread so you won't have any problems manipulating GUI elements.

A more recent option is to use [asynchronous programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), which in this case can be done by simply changing your click handler to this:

```
private async void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        DisplayNextRandomImage();
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
}
```

Neither method handles the case of the user clicking the button twice, but that should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score -2):

Make a  `Queue<Storyboard>`. And add all the image list ,load the first image and then after 10s , you can dequeue the next storyboard and load the image, when that finishes it dequeues the next one and starts that, and so on.